# UITextView loses height

Tags: ios, size, uitextview

I have simple textview with dynamic height, because I want it to conform to its content. But every time when I finish typing text, and begin to do it again, the textview loses his height and comes back to initial height. And yes, I'm a new to iOS development. Here is my code

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{

if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textView endEditing:true];
    return false;
}

return true; 
}


-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    self.myTextView.text = self.myTextView.text.uppercaseString;

    int lines = self.myTextView.contentSize.height / self.myTextView.font.lineHeight;
    NSLog(@"number of lines: %d", lines);

    if (lines >=2) {

        if (lines != optionLineChek) {

            CGSize size = [self.myTextView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:self.myTextView.contentSize];
            CGRect frame = self.myTextView.frame;
            frame.size.height = size.height;
            self.myTextView.frame = frame;

        }

    } 
 }
```

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD4gr.gif)

Comment: if you have top space and bottom space constraints both, remove one.  just add only one and re-check

Comment: don't have them. It's very strange issue for me